# Word problem- ages

Tags: word-problem

The sum of $L$'s and $T$'s ages is $34$. Five years ago, the sum of $2l$ and $3t$ was $61$ years. How old are they now?

Please hint me to what my equations should look like (linear systems).

Ok, so I know that $l+t= 34$ is eq 1, For pt 2 I know its something along the lines of $2l+3t=61$ but there's something missing ($5$ years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first equation will be

$ l + t = 34 $

Second equation will be

$ 2(l -5) + 3 (t-5) = 61 $

By solving above equations simultaneously, you will get your required values of l and t. Hope, it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If we let `L` be L's age today, then five years ago, L's age was `L-5`.

Does that help?